# render an .Rmd from R Script to create .pdf fails

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown, render, pdflatex

I am trying to run rmarkdown:render

```
rmarkdown:render (input = "filename.Rmd",
  output_format = "pdf_document",
  output_file = "filename.pdf")
```

in an R Script to create pdf from an .Rmd file and I get this error:

Error: Failed to compile filename.tex.
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"pdflatex" -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "filename.tex"' had status 1

It creates a .TeX but not a .pdf.
"Knit to PDF" from the .Rmd file works properly. Also, when I replace .pdf with .docx to create word documents, it works perfectly fine!
Any ideas?

Comment: Is `pdflatex` installed properly?  What do you get if you run `system("pdflatex --help")`?

Comment: I think it's installed properly. This is the message i get when I run system("pdflatex --help")                                                             
 Usage: pdflatex [OPTION...] [COMMAND...]
      -alias=APP                      Pretend to be APP.  This affects both
                                      the format used and the search path.
      -aux-directory=DIR              Use DIR as the directory to write

Comment: Do you have a `filename.log` file left behind after the error?  If not, you'll probably get one using `system('pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "filename.tex"')` (i.e. the command that `rmarkdown::render` tried to run).  It should give a bit more detail about the error if it happens again.

Comment: No filename.log has left behind.

Comment: Try the `pdflatex` call from the command line.

Comment: It works when I run it in R Console, but it gives me the same error when I run it in RStudio Console or RStudio Script. There might be something wrong with RStudio installation. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: What does the log file look like when you run the command in the RStudio Console?

Comment: I do not know where to find the log file!

Comment: If `pdflatex` runs, it will put the log file in the same directory as the `.tex` file.  This string of comments is a really inefficient way to help you.  You should edit your question to describe the experiments you've done, showing the results and errors and error messages from the log files (if you can find them!) when things are failing.

Answer (score 0):

I too, had this problem. I installed and uninstalled MikTex. I tried reinstalling tinytex. I rebooted my computer. I searched on forums.

2.5 hours later I happened upon this:

https://yihui.name/knitr/options/

Which notes:

> Chunk options must be written in one line; no line breaks are allowed
> inside chunk options;
>
> **Avoid spaces and periods** in chunk labels and
> directory names; if your output is a TeX document, these characters
> can cause troubles (in general it is recommended to use alphabetic
> characters with words separated by - and avoid other characters), e.g.
> setup-options is a good label, whereas setup.options and chunk 1 are
> bad; fig.path='figures/mcmc-' is a good prefix for figure output, and
> fig.path='markov chain/monte carlo' is bad; non-alphanumeric
> characters except - and _ in figure filenames will be replaced with _
> automatically;

**I replaced all my spaces in my chunk names with hyphens and the report rendered perfectly**. I hope this helps someone else save time!! Thanks Yihui for this reference!